# The old owner and the new owner of the smart contract

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, fallback-function

I encountered such a problem, when i imported the smart contract unto remix, i did this through ABI...ok

one wallet created two contracts, different times, the first contract is now worthless. i'm trying to interact with a second contract via an ABI. when i load the address of the second contract and click it to the owner button, it throws the address of the first contract howevwe, i have the address of the second contract uploaded.

[image]

there is something like this in ABI

[image]

WHAT do you think, whatever function i call, it is better to change ,,newowner,, instead ,,owner,,?

thanks

Comment: very hard to help without seeing code. where'd you get the abi? throws address? are those events? what function let's you change the owners?

Comment: The contract is verified etherscan, i using   this fallback code;

  constructor() { owner = payable(msg.sender); }

  modifier onlyOwner {
        require(
            msg.sender == owner,
            "caller is not the owner"
        );
        _

  function contribute() public payable { }

  function withdraw() public onlyOwner { owner.transfer(address(this).balance); }

  fallback() external payable {
    require(msg.value > 0);
    owner = payable(msg.sender);
  }

  function getBalance() public returns(uint) { bal = address(this).balance; }    
}

Comment: how about post the contract address so we can look at it. without formatting, it's very hard work reading the above code

Comment: i have edited  the post,please see, i have include a code snippet, according to this code is it possible to change the owner?  it appears that the previous contract address is the owner of the current contract address

Comment: please post the addresses for both contracts so we can see all the code.

if the owner of contract 2 is contract 1, you can only change the owner of contract 2 by calling transferOwnership from contract 1

Comment: Does it mean that if I change the owner of the first contract I can access the second contract?

Comment: it's very hard to answer without seeing all the code, but I can't see it helping. Your first contract needs to have a function that will call the change owner function on the other contract. If you post the addresses of the contracts I can tell exactly where things stand